# vbscript sendkeys on windows10 fails on one PC

Tags: windows-10, vbscript

I'm trying to use a vbscript with *sendkeys* but the keys are not recognized.

I'm using a sample from Microsoft and it works on my laptop but **not** on my desktop. On the desktop, Notepad *does* open, but the *sendkeys* "hello" is *not* shown. The same version of Windows 10 is on both laptop and desktop.

Is there something I have to install or activate to be able to use *sendkeys*?

not.vbs

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "notepad.exe"
WScript.Sleep 2000
objShell.SendKeys "Hello"
```

I understand that it's probably a configuration issue, but I don't know where to look.

Comment: not related. the script runs, junt don't work the part where I use sendkeys. in fact, the example I posted open notepad normally, junto don't write "hello"

Comment: Since notepad opens, and there are no external COM objects involved, neither one of the links above will provide a solution.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you add the line `objShell.AppActivate "Untitled - Notepad"` immediately before the SendKeys line? I suspect something is causing the focus to change during that 2 second sleep.

Comment: SendKeys should be avoided at all costs. Always look for an alternative approach. And if you must use a SendKeys type of solution, you will get better reliability using AutoIt or AutoHotKey. That said, I'll try to help, but please note that VBScript SendKeys will typically fail if the user changes focus, even if your script switches focus back to the correct window, and pauses, before attempting the SendKeys.

Comment: @LesFerch I0m receptive to AutoIT, I've tried but it's the same problem. I have a script: `Run("notepad"); Sleep(2000); Send("hello")` and it open notepad but don't write the word, that's why I believe that the problem is in my system

Comment: Please try your VBScript example in [Safe Mode](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2304-boot-into-safe-mode-windows-10-a.html) (I have confirmed that you can run VBScript code in Safe Mode). If it runs correctly in Safe Mode, that should give us some clues to solve this. Also, please consider letting us know what you're actually trying to accomplish. Maybe we can find a solution that doesn't require SendKeys.

Comment: I've tried safe mode, same result. I'm trying to automate login on an app that doesn't have cli option. I intend to enter password on a checkbox and press enter

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. It may be something low-level like the keyboard driver. Is there anything different about the PC where it fails, in relation to input devices or input configuration (such as languages or input method editors)? Does that PC have other devices connected to it? Is the keyboard connected via a hub or monitor? Is there any chance that some AV or security software is blocking SendKeys (although I'd be surprised if such a block was still there in Safe Mode).

Comment: I'm out of ideas too. I've already tried to disconnect the keyboard and configured other languages and no luck. My best guess is replace the machine. I've tried several computers and works on all except this one

Comment: Try a [Windows repair install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). It will repair the Windows installation without removing data or apps.

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing but I believe we should share it as it could happen to others. Following the selective boot idea I finally managed to use sendkeys. After all, the problem was the computer had anydesk with privacy mode enabled, which was blocking sendkeys also. I apologize to everyone and thank you for trying to help

Comment: So, AnyDesk was still running when you booted into Safe Mode previously? Or were you using AnyDesk, on another computer, to access the computer that was booted into Safe Mode? Neither of which makes sense to me (i.e. it should not be possible).

Comment: Yes, I've tried diferent boot combinations and when I tried whitout anydesk It worked (yes, it seems that some safe boot options still run anydesk)